# Application Name Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, interface-builder

I am about to submit my application.  I have already specified the application name on iTunes Connect.  But what will display under the icon on my app when installed by users.

Lets say I named my app colorPicker in xcode, will that appear when I distrubute my app as it does when I test on my iphone?  If so how can I change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this in the plist that is part of your app with the setting:  Bundle display name

Comment: Right now its currently ${PRODUCT_NAME} will that mess anything up and how should I input the name

Comment: You can just type the name in you would like.  No special formatting required that I have found.

Comment: Thanks, I'm paranoid to change anything in the plists.  Had a lot of issues with distributing

Comment: I have changed that setting on two that have been approved, if that gives you any confidence...